# Which is the best NPM JS library to use for a English dictionary lookup?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I need to validate English words. I have used https://www.npmjs.com/package/an-array-of-english-words but it is not comprehensive. Please suggest me a good JS NPM library. Thanks.